# Rendering a Global or a Var in a Php echo

Tags: php, global-variables, echo, global

I found a good script anti spam robots. To implement it in my dynamic pages I have to paste this code:

```
<?php echo hide_email('test@test.com'); ?>
```

Since my pages are dynamic, my emails are stored in Globals

```
%%GLOBAL_Email%% 

<?php echo hide_email('%%GLOBAL_Email%%'); ?>  <--- The email is not rendered
```

Even if I transform the Global in a var it does not work, I tryed the following:

```
<?php echo hide_email(' . $email . '); ?> 
<?php echo hide_email('" . $email . "'); ?>
```

Answer:

```
<?php echo hide_email($email); ?>
```

The question was simple, the answer too.

Comment: so we should just magically know what this `hide_email` script does, or why `%%GLOBAL_Email%%` is a special value? Plus, you need to learn basic PHP syntax, otherwise you're going to keep producing badly wrong code like your last two examples: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

Comment: I do not think it matters how the script works, my question is about rendering a var in a php echo.

Comment: Then go read the link I posted above, and learn how to use PHP properly.

Comment: We are not here to do your job for you. We're here to help. But help is not covering your butt because you can't/won't do it yourself.

Comment: You are not helping at all, you are just expressing your frustration.

Comment: Please do note that Stackoverflow is meant *for programmers*, hobbyist or professional. It is not meant for *non-programmers* to get their code written for them. Having said that, let's keep it constructive guys, okay?

Comment: @deceze once in a while we get bad replies. Not a big deal. Overall this forum helped me a lot, so, I am grateful. By the way, my answer should be marked as solved (by me!).

Comment: Then you should post it as an answer. Go ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
<?php echo hide_email($email); ?>
```